# OpenCV: undefined reference to cv::imwrite

Tags: c++, opencv

Opencv cannot link cv::imwrite during linking. I am linking imgcodecs but still getting link error for imwrite. Interestingly no error for cv::imread only for cv::imwrite.

**Opencv Version**: 3.3.1

**Compiler**: gcc 4.4.7

**Link line:** -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -llibjasper -lIlmImf -llibjpeg -llibpng -llibtiff -llibwebp -lzlib  -la_baslt -lbsc -lbsi -lbigparmcm -lparmsdata -lses -lbregacclib -lbregdb -lbbcacheapi -lbregutil -lcomdb2api -ldbutil -lpeutil -lparmsbase -le_ipc -lbbmsgbufs -lbbipc -lsysutil -lunwind -lz

Comment: there is a opencv_videoio lib, but not sure whether imwrite is part of this or of _imgcodecs

Comment: Please show the complete compilation/link command.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I cannot share it publicly, some part of it uses internal libraries.

Comment: Our internal tools were rewriting opencv header files. Fixed after making changes to build system

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know imwrite is a part of highgui module (opencv 2.4) and imgcodecs for opencv 3.x.x. But its important what compiler and opencv version you are using. For example for mingw you need  -lopencv_imgcodecs320 (for opencv 3.2.0)